# Tomcat SSL connection refused

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tomcat7, keytool

I want to do 2way TLS with tomcat,

I configured tomcat as:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="${user.home}/keystore/keystoregodaddyclient.jks" keystorePass="test"
               truststoreFile="${user.home}/keystore/keystore.jks" truststorePass="test"      
               truststoreType="JKS" disableUploadTimeout="true"   
               enableLookups="true" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
               maxSpareThreads="75" minSpareThreads="25"
               clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I have a certificate and private key from the third party.

I created my "keystore" and trusted" keystore" as follows

Keystore creation:

(a) Create pks keystore.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name clientkey -in godady.crt -inkey server.key -out keystore.p12
```

(b) Import the same to keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystoregodaddyclient.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias clientkey
```

(c)I have created the trusted keystore as:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias clientkey -file godady.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

But my request is refused by the server and getting error as:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

Wanted to know if the keystore was correctly formed, because the same works with self signed certificate.

Comment: And the log messages for the HTTPS connector when Tomcat starts are ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **private key** in the keystore and the **keystore** itself have the **same password**!

Test it by setting the existing password again. If this works, your private key and your keystore have the same password

`keytool -keypasswd -new mystorepass -keystore keystore.ks -storepass mystorepass -alias cybereyepk -keypass mystorepass`